# In-Line editor appears wrong in IE 8.001

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, internet-explorer, inline-editor

In-Line editor appears wrong in IE 8.001 
Does anybody experience same problems? Is there solution for this?

[image]

Comment: I just tried this in IE9 under Compatibility Mode and you get _nothing_ at all (well, the vote control is there.)

Comment: I can reproduce this in IE7 mode, but not in IE8 mode -- are you sure you're not running in compat mode?

Comment: When I turn compability mode on, nothing shows (blank field instead of post edit)

Comment: ah, you're right; never mind

Comment: I have this issue on IE8 as well. I'm noting that it only happens on answers, not the question itself. To get around this until it gets fixed, I'm just using the normal edit interface (hold Shift when clicking `edit`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We were adding a `<div>` directly to a `<tr>`. IE doesn't like that; the other browsers didn't care too much.

I guess we can't blame IE this time; this was plain wrong.

Fixed now.

Comment: If this was the case, why did it only affect answers? Is the logic different between answer and question? Perhaps, to account for tags/title?

Comment: @GraceNote: I haven't checked; when you create invalid HTML, all bets are off (and in IE7 mode, it actually *did* break for questions as well).

Comment: @balpha: Also, is there reason not to allow in-line editing in meta.SO ?

Comment: @genesis: Inline editing *is* allowed here. You just don't have editing privileges here.